# Convert doc, docx, xls, xlsx to PDF (without office installed) with powershell (for free)

Tags: excel, powershell, ms-word, ms-office, converters

Do any of you know a way to convert office docs (docx & xlsx) to pdf without having office installed?

I need to convert it on a server and hope to keep it office free.

This needs to be done with powershell, since I later need to create a recurring script for it.

Answer (score 0):

Well... You have many online converters. Examples:

- http://convertonlinefree.com/
- https://online2pdf.com/convert-docx-to-pdf

Just search the Google :).

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I need to do it with powershell. I need to make a script to edit convert many files every 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a lot of items converted, for free and from various Office applications, you should get yourself a dedicated PC with Office installed and a PDF printer, and then just invoke Office via COM objects, load the docs to convert and call `print()` with proper parameters. Powershell is capable of doing this. If you want to get by with no Office installed due to license reasons, use OOo (it's free) and do the same calling OOo executionables via command line. You can also use an Office-aware PDF converter, like [this one](http://www.a-pdf.com/office-to-pdf/index.htm) ($50), although free converters may exist as well.